# Overloading post-increment operator

Tags: c++

```
MyClass MyClass::operator++(int) {
    return ++(*this);
}
```

That's the code I have written. I works correctly, but all tutorials say that I have to create a temporary object and return it:

```
MyClass MyClass::operator++(int) {
    MyClass tmp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
}
```

Please tell me which way is the best?

Comment: What you've implemented is pre-increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second One!
Post Increment means that the variable is incremented after the expression is evaluated.

Simple example:

```
int i = 10;
int j = i++;

cout<<j; //j = 10
cout<<i; // i = 11
```

Your First example would make `j = 11`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

The first version is wrong, because it returns the new value. The postincrement operator is supposed to return the old value.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorials are correct.

Your version returns the wrong value. The post-increment operator is supposed to return the *previous* value, not the new value. Check for yourself with a plain old int:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x++;
cout << x << y << endl; // prints 56, not 66.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's due to the definition of post-increment operator.

**post-increment** operator: Increments *AFTER* the value is used.

**pre-increment** operator: Increments *BEFORE* the value is used.

So if you do it your way, the value returned from the function is the incremented one.

The tutorials increment the object itself, but return a non incremented *COPY* of the object.